# Incorrect output of Linked List (c++)

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linker

I'm trying to write a linked list of `Node` objects, where each `Node` contains: a string - `data`, and a pointer - `next`. To manage the list (e.g: add/remove nodes), I have Node objects: `head`, `curr` and `temp`. The code compiles fine, but the result is not what I want.

What I'm having trouble with is making the `next` pointer in the `curr` node actually point to the next node. I've been adding output statements to narrow down the error and it seems to be coming from the line: `curr.setNext(n);` in the `addNode()` function.

**LinkedList.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

LinkedList::LinkedList() {

}

void LinkedList::addNode(value_type addData) {
    Node n;
    n.setData(addData);

    if (head.getData() != "") {
        curr = head;

        while(curr.getNext() != NULL) {
            curr = *(curr.getNext());
        }

        curr.setNext(n);    //This line is not linking the nodes.
        cout << "(2) Curr is pointing to: " << curr.getNext() << " , The location of n is:" << &n << endl;
    }
    else {
        head = n;
    }
}
```

**LinkedList.h:**

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
#include "Node.h"

class LinkedList {
    public:
        typedef std::string value_type;

        LinkedList();
        LinkedList(value_type setData);
        void addNode(value_type addData);

    private:
        Node head;
        Node curr;
        Node temp;

};

#endif
```

**Node.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

Node::Node() {
    data = "";
    next = NULL;
}

void Node::setData(value_type setData) {
    data = setData;
}

string Node::getData() { 
    return data;
}

void Node::setNext(Node n) { 
    next = &n;
    cout << "(1) Curr is pointing to: " << next << " , The location of n is:" << &n << endl;
}

Node * Node::getNext() {
    return next;
}
```

**Node.h:**

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

class Node {
    private:    
        typedef std::string value_type;

        value_type data;
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;

    public:
        Node();

        void setData(value_type setData);
        value_type getData();
        void setNext(Node n);
        Node * getNext();
};

#endif
```

So when I call the function a few times with test strings and a blank list, the `cout` statements should be printing out the same memory address in both instances. However, this is the output:

```
(1) Curr is pointing to: 0x22c9a0 , The location of n is:0x22c9a0
(2) Curr is pointing to: 0x22c9a0 , The location of n is:0x22c960
(1) Curr is pointing to: 0x22c9a0 , The location of n is:0x22c9a0
(2) Curr is pointing to: 0x22c9a0 , The location of n is:0x22c960
(1) Curr is pointing to: 0x22c9a0 , The location of n is:0x22c9a0
(2) Curr is pointing to: 0x22c9a0 , The location of n is:0x22c960
```

So in the `Node` class, the memory addresses line up correctly. But as soon as it leaves that class and prints again, they are different. Does it have something to do with `next` and `curr.getNext()` being stored differently? How would I go about fixing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with your debugger and seeing what it does?

Comment: There are several problems.  Start with this:  setNext should take a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a copy of the nodes, rather than operating on the linked list;

This line copies the node

```
curr = *(curr.getNext());
```

Try instead to change `Node curr;` to `Node *curr;` and then operate on pointers instead of copies, like

```
curr = curr->getNext()
```

and

```
curr->setNext(n);
```

You also need to make proper memory management, so code like this will not work as the `Node n` is a local variable will not survived beyound the scope of the function

```
Node n;
n.setData(addData);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, I'll make some changes.

Answer (score 0):

The following function is not right:

```
void Node::setNext(Node n) { 
    next = &n;
    cout << "(1) Curr is pointing to: " << next << " , The location of n is:" << &n << endl;
}
```

You are storing the address of an object that is on the stack. The pointer becomes invalid as soon as the function returns.

**PS** There may be other problems in your code.